# Smoke coming out black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

It DOES create smoke but the smoke is pitch black

i have tried everything, searched everywhere but cannot find a solution! i need white smoke

anyone know of a solution or have had the same problem?

Rendered in Cycles in 2.71.5 using CPU

[image: rendering]

Comment: Voted to close as the problem is solved, but it the exactly solution isn't known.. Seems like it was some obscure system/configuration issue anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have light in your scene, and that the number of volume bounces is greater than 0.

[image]

Also try reducing the amount of absorption or eliminating the absorption entirely. Density*40 will pretty much make the absorption node give solid black unless you have *very* thin smoke to begin with.

Comment: The scene is lit with both standard lighting and environmental lighting, the number of volume bounces is set to 3 for the time being

Comment: Hm.. Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: I tried your setup and it did not work at all (node setup and a sun/sky lamp and environment texture), might be because im working on a quite small scale, but i dont know where i would upload a .blend file privately, i can email it to you if you provide an email address

Comment: The problem has fixed it self after messing arround with a whole bunch of stuff and updating python and the like, unfortunately i dont know what thing in particular fixed it